# TYPO3 direct_mail_subscription with fe_user

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Just a simple question: Does anyone know if direct_mail_subscription works with fe_users or just with tt_address records? I use both for my newsletter recipients but the unsubscribe link only works for tt_address users. Did I forget to configure something or will it just not work with fe_users?

Comment: It depends on what you need? If you want to give the opportunity to subscribe for alredy registered users it is one solution. If it is necessary to  create new user every subscription  there is something different)

Answer (score 0):

1) The easiest way to create a new user with a subscription are Finisher in formhandler - here is ready for use EXT https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/formhandler_subscription or here is main settings https://github.com/astehlik/typo3-extension-formhandler_subscription/blob/master/Configuration/Settings/setup.txt

2) Create form by PowerMail and add Finisher to save fe_user and direct_mail settings here is manual https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/1.6.11/Powermail/Features/SavingDbValuesToAnyDbTable/Index.html#example-typoscript-setup-to-add-values-to-fe-users. You need just add direct_mail fields  which you need for mailing

3) You can override regular EXT. I found best one https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dmailsubscribe. But like every good EXT it work just with tt_addres. But if you know how - you can override Class instand adding tt_adreess add fe_user by FrontendUser\FrontendUserRepository 
If this answer will get 5 likes - I will give example:)